# android Separator after last item of ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, divider

I have two listviews and two different adapters for them. one shows the bottom divider but the other list does not show divider after the last item.
The one which shows divider after last item, only has listview in the layout. other one which does not shows divider has other views along with the listview.

both listviews have the same style which is below.

```
<style name="st_comman_data_list">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/app_background_color</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/app_background_color</item>
    <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">true</item>
    <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">true</item>
    <item name="android:fadingEdge">none</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_states_color</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarFadeDuration">1000</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

**Edit**
layout xml for correct divider

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/app_background_color_light"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/gift_home_ui_home_list"
    style="@style/st_comman_data_list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

xml which don't shows divider

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/app_background_color"
android:cacheColorHint="@color/app_background_color"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_header"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tab_video_main_btn_all"
        style="@style/st_btn_top_header_gry"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:text="@string/st_tab_main_btn_all" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tab_video_main_btn_my_videos"
        style="@style/st_btn_top_header_gry"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:text="@string/st_tab_video_main_btn_my_videos"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tab_video_main_btn_saved"
        style="@style/st_btn_top_header_gry"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:text="@string/st_tab_main_btn_saved" />
</LinearLayout>

<View style="@style/st_single_black_line" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/video_search_holder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background_header_small"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:stretchColumns="0"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_basic_very_large"
        android:background="@drawable/audio_search_bg"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_basic_2dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_basic_2dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/video_btn_search_clear"
                style="@style/st_search_ui_ic_search"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_search"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/video_btn_search"
                style="@style/st_search_ui_ic_search"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/video_search_edit_text"
                style="@style/st_search_ui_search_bar"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/video_btn_search_clear"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/video_btn_search"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:hint="@string/hint_search_by_video_title_or_description"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/no_more_text_list"
    style="@style/st_no_more_text_list"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/video_chanel_list"
    style="@style/st_comman_data_list" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/invisible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />
```

Solutions which i have tried:

1. set height as "match_parent"
2. add a view under the list view and make it invisible
3. set footer divider as enabled (which is true by default)

Someone have any ides why it is behaving differently?

[image: bottom divider]
[image: no divider]

Comment: please share ur code here xml code

Comment: @KarthikaPB i have posted the code in the question

Comment: remove <View
    android:id="@+id/invisible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />                  if it's not working try to add divider property in the style.xml